# Is there a way to hint the passed argument type to IDE (in my case Webstorm) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, type-hinting

I have the following `HTML` file with some `JavaScript` in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<div>
    <label for="new-content">
        <textarea id="new-content" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="addContent(document.getElementById('new-content'))">Submit</button>
</div>


<script>
    function addContent(/*HTMLTextAreaElement*/content) {
        alert(content.value);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I like how I can hint Webstorm (or IntelliJ or Eclipse) what is the type of `content` is in `function addContent`, but I do not like how I can not tell what it is in `onclick`, which leads to following warning:

[image]

Here is my first world problem: Can I hint the type of `document.getElementById('new-content')` in the argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way by trial and error, the following seems to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<div>
    <label for="new-content">
        <textarea id="new-content" style="width: 400px; height: 100px"></textarea>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="addContent(getNewContent())">Submit</button>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
    function getNewContent() {
        return document.getElementById('new-content');/*HTMLTextAreaElement*/
    }

    function addContent(/*HTMLTextAreaElement*/content) {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML +
            '<p>'.concat(content.value).concat('</p>');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```